# Angularness authenticating user with resolve and http.get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Right now I have a simple angular set up that has a login state and a cloud state. I want to make it so the cloud state can only be run if a user is authenticated. And if not, it will direct them to the login state.

So far I believe I have the "resolve" setup and I have the `.run()` function set up to redirect to the login state if there the resolve fails.

My only issue is, no matter what, my `authenticated` variable get's returned un-defined. I'm not sure how to incorporate the `$http.get`.

I'm new to angular, so If anyone has any suggestions, I'd gladly appreciate them.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

 .factory('Auth', function($http, $state, $q) {

    var factory = { isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn };
    return factory;

    function isLoggedIn() {
        $http.get('/auth/user').then(function(data) {
            return true;
        });
    }

})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');

    var authenticated = ['$q', 'Auth', function ($q, Auth) { 
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) deferred.resolve(); else deferred.reject();
        return deferred.promise;
    }];

    var authGuest = function($state, Auth) {
        if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) $state.transitionTo('cloud');
    }

    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: "pages/templates/login.html",
            onEnter: authGuest
        })

        .state('cloud', {
            url: '/cloud',
            templateUrl: "pages/templates/account.html",
            resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
        })

})
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $log) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function () {
        $state.go('login');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing service method should return promise from `isLoggedIn`, other method should be using that promise to resolve it. Then you don't need to use use `Auth.isLoggedIn()` in `if` because anyhow it would be going to return an promise with `catch`, `then` & `finally` in it.

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    retutn $http.get('/auth/user');
}
```

Then those method would be resolved using promise

```
var authenticated = ['$q', 'Auth', function ($q, Auth) { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Auth.isLoggedIn().then(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    }, function(error){
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}];

var authGuest = function($state, Auth) {
    Auth.isLoggedIn().then(function(){
       $state.transitionTo('cloud');
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried what you said but I get the following error: `Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Auth.isLoggedIn().then')`

Comment: @bryan  did you returned promise from `isLoggedIn` like `retutn $http.get('/auth/user');`

Comment: never mind, it was cacheing old js. this works great, thank you. Is my `onEnter` to redirect from `/login` if a user is logged in fine, or is there a better way to do a resolve so that it doesn't load the page first?

Comment: may be stateChanges event would be helpful..do upvote if it does helped you. Thanks :)